# How to mock FlutterDocumentPicker for Flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

I'm mocking `FlutterDocumentPicker` using below code:

```
var binding = // current test binding;
  const MethodChannel channel = MethodChannel('flutter_document_picker');

  binding.defaultBinaryMessenger
      .setMockMethodCallHandler(channel, _mockDocumentPickerHandler);


Future<Object?> _mockDocumentPickerHandler(MethodCall message) async {
  if (message.method == 'pickDocument') {
    final Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final File file = await File(
      '${tempDir.path}/doc.pdf',
    ).writeAsBytes(await _getBytes());

    print("Selecting path for file picker ${file.path}");
    if (message.arguments["isMultipleSelection"]) {
      return [file.path];
    } else {
      return file.path;
    }
  } else {
    throw UnimplementedError(
        "Mock method ${message.method} call for method channel flutter_document_picker is not handled");
  }
}
```

This works great in case of `IO` devices but not in web. As in web there is no support for `getTemporaryDirectory` and the return type of method is expected to be a `File path(String)`, how to store a mock file at a temporary path and return that path?

the File selection code in flutter also expects a file path only, my query is how to mock file picking for Integration tests in flutter web?